# How to have undefined inputs and outputs?

Tags: scala

The code

```
def partval(partID: Int, iter: Iterator[T >: Nothing]): Iterator[T >: Nothing] = {
            iter.map( x => (partID, x) ).toList.iterator }
```

does not work. The exact type in the Iterator should not matter in this code and I thought that everything should be supertype of `Nothing`. I thought the Scala compiler could infer the types so I expected even

```
def partval(partID: Int, iter: Iterator): Iterator = {
            iter.map( x => (partID, x) ).toList.iterator }
```

or

```
def partval(partID, iter) = {
            iter.map( x => (partID, x) ).toList.iterator }
```

to work, but it doesn't. How do I get this to run?

---

Edit:

The signature `def partval(partID: Int, iter: Iterator[T]): Iterator[(Int, T)]` results in

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:19: error: not found: type T
       def partval2(partID: Int, iter: Iterator[T]): Iterator[(Int, T)] = {
                                                                    ^
<console>:19: error: not found: type T
       def partval2(partID: Int, iter: Iterator[T]): Iterator[(Int, T)] = {
```

Comment: if I got you right, you want `def partval(partID: Int, iter: Iterator[T]): Iterator[(Int, T)]`. Also, why do you need `.toList.iterator`?

Comment: @VitaliyKotlyarenko: What do you mean with your last question? Why I want an iterator? That is just the required output. Why `toList`? I am not sure, but without it it does not work.

Comment: @VitaliyKotlyarenko: Your signature results in an error (see question).

Comment: sure, you need to define type parameter T somewhere (I guess you already did it on class level). Try `def partval[T](partID: Int, iter: Iterator[T]): Iterator[(Int, T)]`. I asked about toList, since you map on Iterator returns another Iterator, and you don't need to do double transformation to List and back to Iterator

Comment: @VitaliyKotlyarenko: No, I did not define T. I am using the method as a function in a `map`. How should I define T? Should I remove `toList` or `iterator`?

Comment: 1) check my previous comment (T is type parameter of function definition - partval[**T**]); 
2) you should remove both - just map input iterator and you'll get another iterator

Comment: @VitaliyKotlyarenko: That worked. Make it an answer, so that I may except it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify any type bounds to accept all types:

```
def partval[T](partID: Int, iter: Iterator[T]): Iterator[(Int, T)] = {
  iter.map(x => (partID, x))
}
```